# Event Triggers - Use Cases

Tags: apex, platform-event

I was reading the summer 19' release notes and saw the section about [event triggers](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_change_event_triggers.htm).

Can someone please explain what are those triggers? For which use cases should I use them?

Comment: why was my question downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called "change event triggers," not "event triggers." A "change event" is generated when a record is edited and a field changes from one value to another. Its primary purpose is to allow you to synchronize changes to other objects and/or systems asynchronously. For example, you might update a website's account database when an account in Salesforce is modified. The best part about these new triggers is it only includes changed values, which can reduce the amount of processing time required to evaluate if any additional actions are required.